# C++ Dynamically detect class of parameter and cast thereto

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I have two classes, one which inherits from the other. The relevant part of the base class is as follows (obviously this class has ctors, a dtor, etc., and particularly an `operator[]`, but I thought those irrelevant to the matter at hand):

```
#include <array>

template < class T, unsigned int N >
class Vector
{
public:
    template < class U, unsigned int M > friend Vector< U, M > operator+ ( const Vector< U, M >&, const Vector< U, M >& );

    template < class U, unsigned int M > friend std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream&, const Vector< U, M >& );
};
```

The derived class (again, obviously I've taken out those parts which I thought irrelevant):

```
#include "Vector.h"

template < class T, unsigned int N >
class Polynomial
    : public Vector< T, N >
{
public:
    template < class U, unsigned int M > friend std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream&, const Polynomial< U, M >& );
};
```

(Note: The friend functions use different letters for the templates than the classes do, because otherwise gcc complains about "shadowing". The logic is the same, though.)

`Vector`s print out one way (e.g. `< 3, 5, 1 >`); `Polynomial`s print out another (e.g. `3 x^2 + 5 x + 1`).

This causes a problem, though. When I go to add two `Polynomial`s together, the compiler uses `template < class U, unsigned int M > Vector< U, M > operator+ ( const Vector< U, M >&, const Vector< U, M >& )`, which of course returns a `Vector`. Therefore, if I try to do something like `std::cout << poly1 + poly2;`, the resultant display is in the wrong format.

I would like to modify `template < class U, unsigned int M > Vector< U, M > operator+ ( const Vector< U, M >&, const Vector< U, M >& )` such that it will detect the actual data types of its parameters, and cast the return value accordingly (e.g. return a `Polynomial` if two `Polynomial`s are passed to it). I would like to do this, if possible, without `operator+` knowing about each and every possible subclass of `Vector` (I think this is probably a legitimate desire?), and without making a new `operator+` function for each subclass (since I also have several other overloaded operators, and would like to avoid copying almost exactly the same code ten times for each derived class).

I know that this is possible (and, in fact, relatively easy) in Python. Does C++ support such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you calculate the result as `Vector<T,N>`, you can not simply (legally) cast it to `Polynomial<T,N>`. To achieve the desired effect, you need some deeper modifications. You need a free `operator+`, an implementation that can deliver the desired result type and a way to detect everything derived from `Vector<T,N>`. Let's build it.

a) Detect all `Vector<T,N>`

For that, you could derive from an empty base class that will be optimized away by the empty base optimization (EBO) and that is detectable by `std::enable_if`:

```
struct VectorBase {};

template< class T, unsigned int N >
class Vector
{
  // ...
};
```

now you can check any class `U` if it's derived from `Vector< T, N >` with `std::is_base_of< VectorBase, U >::value`. To be absolutly correct, you need to exclude `VectorBase` itself (`!std::is_same< U, VectorBase >::value`), but that is probably not needed for your use case.

b) An implementation, that deliveres the desired return type. *Before* we do that:

```
template< class T, unsigned int N >
class Vector
{
    template < class U, unsigned int M >
    friend Vector< U, M > operator+ ( const Vector< U, M >&, const Vector< U, M >& );
};
```

should be replaced by:

```
template< class T, unsigned int N >
class Vector
{
    friend Vector< T, N > operator+ ( const Vector< T, N >&, const Vector< T, N >& );
};
```

for the general case. But you need a special return type which can later become `Polynomial<T,N>`, so:

```
template< class T, unsigned int N >
class Vector
{
public:
    template< typename R >
    static R add( const Vector< T, N >& lhs, const Vector< T, N >& rhs )
    {
        static_assert( std::is_base_of<VectorBase,R>::value,
                       "R needs to be derived from Vector<T,N>" );
        R result;
        // implement it here...
        return result;
    }
};
```

c) Provide an `operator+` that calls `add` and that is protected by SFINAE:

```
// as a free function:
template< typename V >
typename std::enable_if< std::is_base_of< VectorBase, V >::value, V >::type
operator+( const V& lhs, const V& rhs )
{
  return V::template add<V>( lhs, rhs );
}
```

Minus some small typos (I haven't tested it), this strategy should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm seeing some code here I'm not familiar with, so I'll do some research.

Comment: @Arandur: I admit it's quite advanced, but I don't see an easier way. Also, note that the code uses C++11 features, so you need a compiler that supports it and, usually, you also need to enable C++11 explicitly.

Comment: Well, it's pretty black magic-y, but it works like a charm! Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: And yeah, I've been using C++11 features anyway, so that works for me. Thanks!