# Subclass a template class with operators

Tags: c++, templates, subclassing

I'm trying to create classes for mathematical vectors in various dimensions, and since they have much in common I created a templated base class with the vectors size as the template parameter. I'm subclassing because I want different constructors (e.g. `Vec2f(float x, float y)`, `Vec3f(float x, float y, float z)`) and additional functions like the cross product for 3 dimensional vectors.

My Problem: What should `operator+` in the baseclass return? If it returns an instance of the baseclass then `Vec3f + Vec3f` returns `Vecnf`, but it should return `Vec3f`. Can this be achieved somehow?

Here is a code example:

```
template <size_t n>
class Vecnf {
public:
   Vecnf operator+(Vecnf const & vec) const {
      return Vecnf(*this) += vec;
   }
   Vecnf & operator+=(Vecnf const & vec) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         elements[i] += vec.elements[i];
      }
      return *this;
   }
protected:
   std::array<float, n> elements;
};

class Vec3f : public Vecnf<3> {
public:
   Vec3f(float x = 0.0f, float y = 0.0f, float z = 0.0f);
   Vec3f crossProd(Vec3f const & vec);
};
```

With this implementation, the following:

```
Vec3f a, b;
Vec3f c = a + b;
```

gives the compile time error

```
error: conversion from 'Vecnf<3u>' to non-scalar type 'Vec3f' requested
```

I'm using TDM GCC version 4.8.1 on Windows 8 Pro. I'm using c++11, so your solution can use it as well, but since I don't think it's crucial I haven't flagged the question with it. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: CRTP would help you here. I'm not sure it would be pleasing though.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15666231) helps?

Comment: `Vec3f` can have a constructor that take a `Vecnf<3>&&`...

Comment: this is a very weird way to use templates...you use a template so that you have the same code for multiple data types;

Comment: the code will not compile because a template is basically code which is datatype independent NOT datasize independent!

Comment: Don't publicly inherit if you don't have virtual destructors. Private inheritance is fine. You can bring inherited members into scope with `using` declaration. As for your question, CRTP will work and non-member operators will too.

Comment: @Pandrei Then what are template non-type parameters meant for? This is a perfectly valid situation for using templates if you ask me. Please see my answer below.

Comment: @Pandrei: what's about `std::bitset<N>` ?

Comment: @Lightness: CRTP really comes closest to what I hoped to find, but it really isn't as pleasing as I hoped. I could combine it with @Jarod42's suggestion to cast the return values, but the thought of being able to pass any type as a template parameter and the returned `Vecnf` or its reference would be cast to it gives me the chills :/ Nonetheless thank you for your great suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the constructor a variadic template, thereby solving your first problem and eliminating the need to even use inheritance:

```
template <size_t n>
class Vecnf
{
    std::array<float, n> elements;

public:
    template <typename ... Args>
    Vecnf(Args ... args): 
        elements {{static_cast<float>(args)...}}
    {}

    // other methods, operators etc...
};
```

Now you can make `typedef`'s for the commonly used sizes if you like:

```
typedef Vecnf<3> Vec3f;
```

In my opinion, you could even improve this by adding another template parameter for the type you want to store in the array. It could default to `float` of course.

Also, it shouldn't be too hard to implement the cross-product in a generic way...

Comment: Or `crossproduct` may be a free function taking 2 `vec3f`.

Comment: This sounds great, but what happens when I do `Vec2f vec(1., 2., 3., 4.)`? Or give it less than the needed amount of parameters to initialize the array fully? Besides the sunblassing also happens so I can create more cast operators. Smaller vectors should be cast to bigger ones implicitly, the other way around it should only happen explicitly since data gets lost. (The crossproduct is only defined on 3 dimensional vectors as far as I know, so it would be fine to be declared as a free function)

Comment: @Svensational The compiler will complain when you try to initialize it with too many elements. When you provide less elements than the size of the vector, the remaining elements will be initialized to 0. This is just the behavior of `std::array`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used your variadic template constructor approach combined with the casting constructor suggested as a comment earlier by @Jarod42 in the daughter classes (except it takes `Vecnf<3u> const &` since I don't think rvalues make a big difference here. The data really only consists of a `std::array` on the stack)
You are my hero ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can just define an operator+ on vec3f that does what you want it to. It can have a differing return type to vecnf's as long as it's a subtype of it and it will still override it.

Better solution is what @JorenHeit introduced; that actually is what you wanted, together with two typedefs. This solution is c++03 compatible though, and his isn't.

Comment: True, but he stated that the solution could use C++11.

Comment: @JorenHeit Yep, but not all future people reading this will realize that. There might also be other reasons to prefer subclassing and knowing about covariant return types is good.

Comment: The problem is I overrode multiple operators (`+, +=, -, -=, *, *=, /, /=, []`). The code for them is very short but it's the same in every vector class. I actually could abandon templates and subclassing at all and copy the operators into every class (after all only three classes make sense for me), but it just feels wrong to copy code. There must be a more elegant way ;)